# CFDocument (CF9) Anyone successfully using "FREE3OF9.TTF " (Barcode font)?

Tags: fonts, coldfusion, barcode, cfdocument

I'm trying to create a pdf with a barcode using CFDocument.  (Barcode font is loaded.  Can see it in the CF admin.)  Found a boat load of folks complaining about the font not being recognized, but no solutions anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

OK, for anyone else having this issue, here is what I did:

> I first added the font in the control panel "fonts" app of the server.
>   I then  added the font in the CF administrator. I noticed that the
>   font face and font  family were both isted as "new". I rebooted and
>   when it came up they were both  still listed as "new". I opened up the
>   TTF file to see what the name was  actually listed as. I then used
>   that name in my css like so "font-family:Free 3  of 9 Extended;". It
>   worked.
>
> I can now print barcode labels using flashpaper. PDF still wants to
>   make  everything portrait for some reason, even though I specify
>   landscape.

*( from http://www.mail-archive.com/cf-talk@houseoffusion.com/msg290047.html )*

CF has the font listed as "free 3 of 9" (with spaces). Make sure to embed the font in cfdocument!

Answer (score 2):

Add the font in your server control panel (windows). Add the font in CF admin  Font management (Under server settings). Restart server (Note: don't skip the restarting of server or it will not work). 
Below is a working sample code of 'Free 3 of 9 extended'

`<cfdocument format="pdf" filename="#expandpath('.')#\barcode.pdf" pagetype="letter" overwrite="yes"
            backgroundvisible="yes" margintop=".33" marginright=".33" marginbottom=".33"
            marginleft=".33" fontembed="yes">
    <p style="font-family:Free 3 of 9 extended;font-size:75px;">
        content here
    </p></cfdocument>`

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Not sure why it's not the accepted answer.